# PHPUnit calling external function as object

Tags: testing

I'm doing a unit testing with my `CVRClient` file using the code below.

```
//CvrapiTest.php

<?php

namespace Drupal\cvr\test\Cvrapi;

use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase;
use cvr\src\Cvrapi\CVRClient;

class CvrapiTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

public function testSearchOnlyVAT()
    {
        $result = \Cvrapi\CVRClient::request('29910251', 'dk', 'vat', 'Unit Testing');

        $this->assertTrue(property_exists($result, 'vat'));
        $this->assertTrue((int)$result->vat === 29910251);
    }
```

I have a `CVRClient` class under `cvr/src/Cvrapi` folder that queries data from an api.

I know that `phpunit` command is working fine but I'm getting the error below.

> Fatal error: Class 'cvr\src\Cvrapi\CVRClient' not found in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/query/modules/custom/cvr/test/Cvrapi/CvrapiTest.php
>   on line 17

NOTE: It's the `\Cvrapi\CVRClient::` that causes the error. If I remove this line, I need to have a code to assign values to `$result`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `use` declaration is incorrect, and is causing your call to the client to look in the wrong namespace. You probably need to change this:

```
use cvr\src\Cvrapi\CVRClient;
```

To this:

```
use Cvrapi\CVRClient;
```

And change this:

```
$result = \Cvrapi\CVRClient::request('29910251', 'dk', 'vat', 'Unit Testing');
```

To this:

```
$result = CVRClient::request('29910251', 'dk', 'vat', 'Unit Testing');
```

Comment: Still giving me the same error but this time: `Class 'Cvrapi\CVRClient'`

Comment: Open the file `cvr/src/Cvrapi/CVRClient.php`, and paste the namespace declaration inside it here.

Comment: this is the namespace of my CVRClient.php `namespace Drupal\cvr\src\Cvrapi;`

Comment: I think I might see the problem. It looks like you are using PHPUnit outside of Drupal, so it's likely it's not able to find autoloaded classes from within Drupal. Are you using Drupal 8? If so, you should be extending UnitTestCase. If D7, I'm not sure what you should be using. You may want to check out a presentation I did recently on Unit Testing in D8: https://www.youtube.com/edit?video_id=becQyZZu2lw (associated slideshow: http://www.slideshare.net/JayFriendly/automated-php-unit-testing-in-drupal-8)

Comment: Yes, I'm using PHPUnit to test in Drupal 8 site, but in D8 they already included PHPUnit and actually it works fine when I try basic testing, on empty classes. Alright, thanks..will try UnitTestCase. BTW, your youtube link is redirected to my uploaded videos :D Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oops, that was the edit link. The video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=becQyZZu2lw